# Empty shared node object after updating across application

Tags: node.js

When I update my node js object, it doesn't update in all classes that require it.

I have availableResources.js module like so

```
module.exports = {}
```

And in my resources.server.js I have a init function like so

```
var AvailableResources = require("./availableResources.js");

var newResource = {
    name    : 'resource1',
    type    : 'video'
}

AvailableResources[newResource.name] = newResource;
console.log("AvailableResources", AvailableResources);
```

and in another file named processor.server.js I'm using this resource like so

```
var AvailableResources = require("./availableResources.js");

function activateResource(resourceName){
    console.log("AvailableResources", AvailableResources);
    AvailableResources[resourceName].activate();
}
```

When I console.log available resources in my resources.server.js I see the added resource with the correct property names. But when I console.log available resources in processor.server.js after I add the resource, I still see an empty object.

How can this object be shared as intended when I update it in one class?

Answer (score 0):

So, when you `require('./availableResources.js')` you are importing any exports from that file to the new location. You can change and manipulate the data in the new file however you please and it will not make any changes at all to the original object being exported.

If you want the results of your actions in `resources.server.js` to be affected by the function call in `processor.server.js` you will have to do the following:

After updating the object with new data, add `module.exports = AvailableResources` to your resources.server.js file. And change your require statement in processor.server.js to be `AvailableResources = require('./resources.server.js')`.

If you are trying to time some action to happen after something is loaded, perhaps you should look into `Promise()` instead of the chained require statements.